# StreamBuilder not updating ListView.builder after data changed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and facing an issue with StreamBuilder & ListView.builder.

I am making a network call on click of a button(Apply Button) available in the list of the card, based on that other buttons are displayed.

the issue I am facing is that widgets are not updated after successful network call but, when I refresh the page I am getting updated result.

What I am doing wrong?

I am not Using any State into this. Do I need to use it?

### Widget Code

```
StreamBuilder(
          initialData: [],
          stream: dataBoc.ListData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    key: Key(snapshot.data[index]["lid"]),
                    child: DataCard(
                      DataModel(snapshot.data[index]),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/detailPage",
                          arguments: snapshot.data[index]["id"]);
                    },
                  );
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

### Bloc Code

//Here is how I am adding data to the stream

```
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      if (data['status'] == true) {
        // listDataStream.sink.add(data['result']);
        listDataStream.add(data['result']);
      } else {
        listDataStream.sink.addError("Failed to Load");
      }
    }
```

Expected result: When I make Network call and if it succeeds then based on network result other buttons must be displayed on the appropriate card.

Comment: Can you provide full source code?

Comment: @nucleartux I have fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I have fixed this issue. The issue was my widget tree was not well structured and it was breaking the Widget build process.

Comment: Can you say what in particular you changed? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @pyetti I restructure my widgets & removed unnecessary widgets